# How to create a report with fields in between paragraph text?

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports

My report is something like below.[image: Report]

In the shown report, text in black color is static and the text in RED are fields to be replaced with some value dynamically by java.

In the above picture, line 1 and 2 I have no problem.

But for the paragraph I am not sure what to use? Should I use static-text box or Text field? If I use part static-text box and part dynamic, its becoming clumsy and difficult to maintain the line spacing.

So please advise how to design the following report in jasper studio 5.6.

Comment: Any comments?, is your problem solved or question still open?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `textField` and then String concatenation on your text, when you need to number format use the [NumberFormat API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) or the [DecimalFormat API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

If you need to break line, set bold text you can use html to achive this by setting  `markup="html"` on the `textElement`

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0ef33a9d-fd2b-46cc-9ec4-c6906db8097b">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="testNumber" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(10000.23445)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="57" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="373" height="57" uuid="2f795f8a-43fa-4b89-a173-76854a13ba48"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Just use a textField and string concat the other text a " + java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format($P{testNumber}) + " as you see you can even format it and remeber if you set as html you can <br/> break line and <b>bold</b> text"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: Result]